# Exporting Google Trends CSV

Tags: google-trends

When exporting into CSV, only one or two of my search terms are populated in the "Interest over time" section. However when scrolling down to the other sections, all my search terms' data is in the file.

Why am I unable to see all the terms' "interest over time" data?

Thanks!!!